# FeatureClass to IFeatureLayer

Tags: arcobjects, feature-layer

I am trying to covert my feature class to feature layer so that i can pass "IQueryByLayer" over my feature class.

Till now i have my feature class ---

```
FeatureClass className = new FeatureClass(cc);
```

want to do something like

```
IFeatureLayer newLayer = className.as---(FeatureLayer)
```

Can anybody point out a correct way to impliment it.

Comment: Is this code running in an ArcMap addin/ ArcObjects custom class?

Comment: No a destop tool where i am providing user to select two different feature classes////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IFeatureLayer` only make sense when your code is working within ArcMap. If that is your case, have a look at this code:

```
IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayerClass();
featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("2000_hrcn");
ILayer layer = (ILayer)featureLayer;
layer.Name = featureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;
// Add the layer to the focus map.
ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument mxDocument = (ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument)(m_application.Document);
IMap map = mxDocument.FocusMap;
map.AddLayer(layer);
//now you can use the the IFeatureLayer
```

Also note that A featureclass cannot be instantiated directly. You can only get it as a result from other methods like IfeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass method.

Code like `FeatureClass className = new FeatureClass(cc);` will not compile

Comment: I know i am getting it through IFeatureClass itration...Isn't there any way so that i can convert my feature class to layer and use it in IQueryByLayer...

Comment: No, It will work only within ArcMap